# link libmysql.lib with gcc or dev c++ in windows

Tags: c++, mysql, mingw

i've been trying to link mysql with c++ below is the code for ref

the file called sqlfunction.cpp has following code which helps connect mysql

```
#include <mysql.h>
#include "rlmodbusclient.h"
#include "modbusdaemon.h"

MYSQL *conn;
MYSQL_RES *res;
MYSQL_ROW row;

bool Opendb(char *pc,char *user, char *pass, char *db)
{

    conn = mysql_init(NULL);
   // Connect to database

   if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, pc,
   user, pass, db, 0, NULL, 0)) {
   fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
   return 0;
   } else return 1;

}
```

now if above called from the program files like this

```
char pc[10]="localhost",user[5]="root",pass[8]="pass",db[6]="database";

   ret = Opendb(pc,user,pass,db);
   printf("opendb_buttonevent = %d\n",ret);
```

this is all good but the only thing is program is not compiling at all

the error is 
undefined reference to mysql_init@4'

i found  one solution for this which is

http://www.openwebspider.org/documentation/how-to-link-libmysqllib-with-dev-c-or-gcc-under-windows/

this link suggest to run reimp.exe with libmysql.lib

i tried to run this but this doesnt make any sense please if some one has done above then explain how to use reimp to solve this issue..

thanks

just like to add command which i'm using to run reimp

```
C:\Documents and Settings\XPMUser\Desktop\mingwutils\bin>reimp.exe "C:\Program F
iles\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\lib\libmysql.lib"
reimp.exe: dlltool: No such file or directory
```

as can be seen it says dlltool: no such file but i found that dlltool is part of 
C:\MinGW\bin directory...  which doesnt make any sense?????

Comment: I am loosing it ... You say it doesn't compile ... Are you compiling in MinGW environment on Windows ? Is the compiled libmysql you are trying to link on is built for your set-up ? You tagged this question a `Qt` one, is QtSQL involve in this ?

Comment: i'm sorry qt sql is not part of myset up i was using it for the same project previously so my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general problem is that the libmysql.lib library is in the Microsoft-specific lib format, which mingw cannot link against. It seems that reimp.exe can convert such libraries and needs dlltool to do so. It probably couldn't find it because it is not in your PATH. Try

set PATH=%PATH%;C:\MinGW\bin
reimp.exe "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\lib\libmysql.lib"

Afterwards, you should gain a libmysql.a file, which must be moved somewhere the mingw linker can find it, e.g. your project directory.